# How can I add a middleware in my route?

Tags: hapi.js

In express I have something like this:

```
router.get('/foo', middlewareFunction, function (req, res) {
    res.send('YoYo');
});
```

What is the form for a middleware in hapi? When I have this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/foo',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('YoYo');
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you want to do in the middleware?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The route *pre* option allows defining such pre-handler methods, please have a look at http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 80 });

const pre1 = function (request, reply) {

    return reply('Hello');
};

const pre2 = function (request, reply) {

    return reply('World');
};

const pre3 = function (request, reply) {

    return reply(request.pre.m1 + ' ' + request.pre.m2);
};

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    config: {
        pre: [
            [
                // m1 and m2 executed in parallel
                { method: pre1, assign: 'm1' },
                { method: pre2, assign: 'm2' }
            ],
            { method: pre3, assign: 'm3' },
        ],
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            return reply(request.pre.m3 + '\n');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i know its kinda newbie question, but how to stop in function 2 if say the auth failed?

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq As per hapi built-in auth plugin mentioned [here](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth) it provides a validate function where you can define your actions like lookup token in db etc. You register your routes that will use this middleware by placing auth object in options of each route. I do not recommend using _pre_ for this.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [server.ext](http://hapijs.com/api#serverextevent-method-options) property to register an extension function in one of the [available extension points](http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle).

For example:

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
    // do something
    return reply.continue();
});
```

This feature might be useful. It all depends in what you want to do with the middleware.

Comment: Sure, I gonna try with the 'onPreHandler' event.

Comment: PS: `continue` is not a function.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @gastonmancini answer, if you are using v17 and above, you might want to use:

```
server.ext('onRequest', (request, h) => {
    // do something
    return h.continue;
});
```

According to [hapi docs](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658):

"Return **h.continue** instead of **reply.continue()** to continue without changing the response."

Answer (score 2):

In Hapi v17 and above, you can use following code

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({
  host: settings.host,
  port: settings.port,
  routes: {cors: {origin: ['*'] } }
});

server.ext('onRequest',async (req, h)=>{
  req.firebase = 'admin'; // This adds firebase object to each req object in HAPI
  return h.continue; // This line is important
})
```

Now access the req.firebase object in your routes like this:

```
 {
        method: 'POST', 
        path: '/helper/admin-object', 
        options: {
            handler: async (req, h)=>{
                console.log(req.firebase); // Prints admin
                return true;
            },

        }
    },
```